# Complete Problems for $DSPACE(\log(n)^k)$

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, space-complexity

We know that the $polyL$-hierarchy doesn't have complete problems, as it would conflict with the space hierarchy theorem. But: Are there complete problems for each level of this hierarchy?

To be precise: Does the class $DSPACE(\log(n)^k)$ have complete problems under $L$-reductions for each $k > 0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A standard proof of the space hierarchy theorem is based on the space-efficient simulation of Turing machines.  If I am not mistaken, this simulation implies that for every space-constructible function *f*: ℕ→ℕ, the following problem is in DSPACE(*f*(*n*)) (where *n* is the input length):

> Given an encoding of a deterministic Turing machine *M* with a read-only input tape and a read-write work tape with a fixed work alphabet (such as {0, 1, blank}), a string *x*, and a tally string 1<sup>*t*</sup>, decide whether *M* halts on input string *x* before using more than *f*(*t*) work space.

This problem is DSPACE(*f*(*n*))-hard under log-space many-one reducibility.  Here is a proof in the case of *f*(*n*) = lg<sup>*k*</sup>*n*.  For each language *L*∈DSPACE(log<sup>*k*</sup>*n*), there is a Turing machine *M* (of the form stated above) which accepts *L* in *c* lg<sup>*k*</sup>*n* space for some *c*∈ℕ.  Modify *M* to *M*′ so that when *M* rejects, *M*′ goes into an infinite loop instead.  Then given an input string *x*, let *t* = |*x*|<sup>*c*</sup>, and we generate the instance (*M*′, *x*, 1<sup>*t*</sup>) of the problem above.  (I think that the only slightly nontrivial part is that we cannot set *t* = |*x*|.)

Therefore this problem is DSPACE(*f*(*n*))-complete under log-space many-one reducibility.

Answer (score 3):

Just an exetended comment.

In the paper "[The Emptiness Problem for Intersections of regular Languages](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.1571&rep=rep1&type=pdf)"  it is showed that deciding the emptiness of the intersection of the languages recognized by 
$g(n)$ DFAs is complete for $NSPACE(g(n)\log{n})$; in particular the emptiness of the intersection of the languages recognized by $\log^{k-1}{n}$ DFAs is complete for $NSPACE(log^{k}{n})$, $k \geq 1$.

But it seems that the same result cannot be restricted to DPSACE if we consider the emptiness intersection of languages recognized by $g(n)$ Tally-DFAs (DFAs with only one symbol in the alphabet).

However $\emptyset = \bigcap^k DFA_{lin}$ is complete for $DSPACE(\log{n})$ for each $k$.